# how to compare xmlhttp.responsetext?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

my code-

```
document.getElementById("lblmsg").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                if(xmlhttp.responseText == 'Available') 
                    {
                         document.getElementById("newid").value = "";
                    }
```

**although response text is `Available` but still it is not going inside if condition???**

Answer (score 6):

Well, that should work.

Are you sure that the response text is exactly Available? Try trimming the response like this:

```
if(xmlhttp.responseText.trim() == 'Available')
```

Do you have access to firebug? Try a console.log(xmlhttp) to find out the exact value of the responseText.

Comment: Just in case if above won't work -- `trim()` is not standard Javascript `String` object method.

Answer (score 2):

After hours of searching I found this pitfall:
http://www.vertstudios.com/blog/avoiding-ajax-newline-pitfall/

This solved everything without `$.trim()`. Somewhere in my included files was a lonely linebreak!