# How to avoid to add one empty char at beginning while reading a file in Java?

Tags: java, file, line-by-line

I have several dictionary files that i read in Java and while reading them line by line, i use this code:

```
       public static void main(String args[]) { 


    try {

        FileInputStream fstream1 = new FileInputStream("de-DE.dic");
                    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream1);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"UTF-8"));

      String str;
      while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
         String str_uc=str.toUpperCase(Locale.GERMAN);
          if(hasApostrophe(str_uc)){
              allletters.add(str_uc);
          if(str.length()==3)
              threeletter.add(str_uc);
          else if(str.length()==4)
              fourletter.add(str_uc);
          else if(str.length()==5)
              fiveletter.add(str_uc);
          else if(str.length()==6)
              sixletter.add(str_uc);
          else if(str.length()==7)
              sevenletter.add(str_uc);
       }
      }
      in.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    }
```

However, it always add one empty char to the first line word and for example if three letter word is in first line,it is added to fourletter array. How can i prevent this happening? Thanks.

ADDITION:

Here is a few lines from the file:

```
Aachens
Aachen
Aal
Aale
Aalen
Aales
Aals
Aas
Aases
Aasgeier
Aasgeiern
Aasgeiers
```

Comment: show few lines from file to be read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Its a note pad issue. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6543595/925202)

Use

```
String str_uc=str.trim().toUpperCase(Locale.GERMAN);
```

trim() will remove whitespace characters at the start or end of the line.

Comment: trim() didn't work out. Still adds empty char to the word at first line.

Comment: can u try to find out what that character is? use - System.out.println((int)str.charAt(0))

Comment: thats why i added a typecast to int value. that will print the ASCII value of the char.

Comment: Here is the ASCII value: 65279

Comment: does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538203/how-to-avoid-echoing-character-65279-in-php-this-question-also-relates-to-java

Comment: probably its a notepad issue: Read more - http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?4193-The-header-of-utf-8-file-Why-there-is-extra-char-quot-quot-when-saving-a-file-as&s=928410e19ce1d4d06fa7a8c78b3e6c7e&p=8761&viewfull=1#post8761

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you, PC =) I changed the encoding to "Turn UTF-8 without BOM" in notepad++ and it worked out. =)

Answer (score 1):

**Probably the correct fix**

Java has two sorts of streams:

Binary streams - these can read any sort of data, but in order to read the data you have to know what sort it is

Text streams - here it is agreed you are reading text

What you are doing is opening a `FileInputStream` which is a form of binary stream and then decorating it with a BufferedReader, which is first decorated by a dataInputStream.

The more correct approach would be to open a FileReader in the first place, and then decorate it (only if you need to, performance wise) with a BufferedReader.

See the JAVA API for [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html)

If you switch to FileReader your 'unexpected' problem will be resolved (this is because the way you read strings from a file when you think you're storing them in binary format, which means DataInput expects to read an 'indication' that these chars are a string before the actual string)

**Quick Fix**
Also, if you don't want to switch, you can always just call the [trim](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) method of the String class.

**Another quick fix**

Use scanner instead of all the streams you're opening, scanner accepts a filename parameter and opens the file, you can use scanner's next() method and has very advanced parsing abilities, see [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: I want to read file in UTF-8 format. How can i add it with Scanner?

Comment: new Scanner("de-DE.dic", "UTF-8");

Comment: Nope. It does the same with Scanner.

Comment: Using Java 8, the `FileReader` nor the `trim` mothod worked for me.  All these solutions failed to get rid of the empty character (char value = 65279)

Answer (score 0):

According to PC.'s answer, I may suggest you to convert your file encoding to following in Notepad++

[image]