# Strange css line break

Tags: html, css, whitespace, line-breaks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid echoing character 65279 in php? (This question also relates to Javascript xmlhttp.responseText (ajax))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538203/how-to-avoid-echoing-character-65279-in-php-this-question-also-relates-to-java)

I can't understand why div behaves so strange, 
There is a div on the right side, which has class - .rightcolumn, it has child div .basket_refresh_box, the problem is that there is a whitespace/breakline before basket_refresh_box div, that is counted as 1 text line, so this div, basket_refresh_box, goes down 1 line, i've tried to remove all whitespaces, so it would look like ..., so there is no even one space or tab character between them, then firebug shows just empty text between them (""), still the div goes down.
Is it possible to remove this pagebreak somehow? 
css white-space doesn't help..

btw i've tried to insert another div right after rightcolumn and it is shown right way,

thanks for your help in advance,

update: i've updated my code so it would look like:
`<div class="rightcolumn"><div id="basket_refresh_box"></div>`

but there is sill this "" empty text before div,

and here's how firebug shows it: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbeO9.jpg

and here's how it's shown in browser:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJYyQ.jpg

Comment: Please don't link directly to your website: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: This looks to be caused by the unicode char `65279`. Possible solutions/duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6538203/681807 && http://stackoverflow.com/q/9691771/681807

Comment: sorry, i should have read rules better, i've edited my post, so it would look better, anyway sometimes it's hard to show something that is not visible and should not exist :)

and i don't think it's unicode char, because now i've cutted out all characters between div, and i still see this "" in firebug

Comment: is your file saved as UTF-8? check for BOM in your file

Comment: Thank you, I've checked all files and resaved it without Byte Order Mark (BOM), that removed all problems

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your file saved as UTF-8, check for Byte Order Mark (BOM) in your file.