# How to get rid of mystery linebreak before widgets in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, widget, line-breaks

For some reason, Wordpress is inserting a linebreak before my widgets that is throwing off my website.

Have a look at http://mytimeforart.com/galleries/pen-and-ink/ at the bottom, where there are 3 columns (Recent TWeets, Inquire With Us, and a blank column). See the gap above the widget titles? That is the result of the mystery linebreak.

This is the source code of the middle widget:

```
<div id="footer-mid">﻿<div class="bottom-widget"><h4>Inquire With Us</h4>           <div class="textwidget">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet cons ecter adipisicing elit, sed a eiuma smod temp incididunt ut<br>
<a href="/contact"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/inquire.png" border="0" style="margin-top:6px"></a></div>
</div></div>
```

and how it is set up in my theme:

```
<div id="footer-mid"><?php get_sidebar('bottom-2'); ?></div>
```

and how it is set up in my functions.php:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
register_sidebar(array('name'=>'Sidebar Bottom 2',
'before_widget' => '<div class="bottom-widget">',
'after_widget' => '</div>',
'before_title' => '<h4>',
'after_title' => '</h4>',
));
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Cynthia

Comment: please check if this sorts your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538203/how-to-avoid-echoing-character-65279-in-php-this-question-also-relates-to-java

Comment: That was it EXACTLY! I thought I had stripped out all of the BOMs but I missed it in 3 sidebar files. Thanks! Repost as an answer so I can select it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have BOM problems; see http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//mytimeforart.com/galleries/pen-and-ink/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654