# PHP include() creates unwanted gaps in HTML

Tags: html, header, footer, html-entities, php-include

I have a document that includes a header (menu) and a footer in PHP:

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

For some reason when opened on the browser it renders a gap between both without having any margins or CSS styles doing it:

[image: HTML gap when using php include()]

This is part of the code generated, the gap appears between  `</header>﻿<footer>`:

```
<div class="ClearFloat"></div>
</nav>
</header>﻿<footer>
<div class="MainWrapper">
<ul>
<li>&copy; Copyright 2013</li>
```

If I inspect using firebug I do see a gap in the code:

```
</nav>
</header>

﻿<footer>
<div class="MainWrapper">
<ul>
```

Furthermore if I try to edit the code in firebug I get a weird entity number where the gap appears: `&#65279;`:

```
</nav>
</header>&#65279;<footer>
<div class="MainWrapper">
<ul>
```

This has to do something with php because if I write the HTML of the header and the footer straight in the page the gap disappears:

[image: HTML gap disappears when not using php include()]

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: check accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538203/how-to-avoid-echoing-character-65279-in-php-this-question-also-relates-to-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As Per** [Why is &#65279; appearing in my HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html)

**it may have a Simple Fix!**

> **The character in question &#65279 is the Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH
>   NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+FEFF) attached to your code on a copy/paste or during a faulty Save
>   its so simple to fix that,
>   just open that file by notepad++ and step follow --> 
>   `Encoding->Encode in UTF-8 without BOM`. then save that. It work for me as well!**

Answer (score 0):

The character in question &#65279 is the Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+FEFF). It may be that you copied it into your code via a copy/paste without realizing it.