# Positioning of a main menu issue

Tags: css

Since some moment in time my main menu on the site (www.dialogue-c.org) dragged a little down from the position where it is supposed to be. I was trying to figure out what happened, and I ended up with this piece of code:

```
<div id="topnav">
 <div class="topnav-inner">
  <div class="topnav">
   "
            "
   <!-- debut Maximenu CK, par cedric keiflin sur http://www.joomlack.fr -->
```

If I delete empty lines in the quotes - menu goes back, how should i solve the problem? If you go to the site, and tap "Inspect the element" after right mouse click, you will see this piece of code (Also if in properties of that piece you change the font size - menu also goes back)

Comment: Enhlish version of the site doesn't have this problem and doesn't have these lines in quotes..how do I find the source of the piece of code?

Comment: This sould fix the problem: `.topnav { line-height: 0; }`.

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP?

Comment: Sorry, updated. Line-height is great, but which file should include this line

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, just before that html comment, you have the Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+FEFF).

Depending on your editor, you may not be able to see it (because it's zero-width). Just use a text editor that shows it (e.g. Notepad++) and remove it.

<sup>Also see [Why is &#65279; appearing in my HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9691771/1529630)</sup>

Alternatively, it may be that you server-side `include` the menu from a file. Using "UTF-8 without BOM" encoding instead of just "UTF-8" will solve the problem.

<sup>Also see [How to avoid echoing character 65279 in php? (This question also relates to Javascript xmlhttp.responseText (ajax))](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6538203/1529630)</sup>