# How can I insert the contents of a file in my index.html with gulp-inject?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-inject

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
gulp.task('watch-index-html', function () {
    gulp.watch(files, function (file) {
        return gulp.src('index/index.html')
            .pipe(inject(gulp.src(['index/base3.html']), {
                starttag: '<!-- inject:base3:html -->'
            }))
            .pipe(print(function (file) {
                return "Processing " + file;
             }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
    });
});
```

Here's what happened:

Before:

```
<body>
    abcd
    <!-- inject:base3:html -->
    <!-- endinject -->
    efgh
```

After:

```
<body>
    abcd
<!-- inject:base3:html -->
<link rel="import" href="/index/base3.html">
<!-- endinject -->
    efgh
```

What I expected to see was the actual contents of the file, not the line:

```
<link rel="import" href="/index/base3.html">
```

Can anyone tell me if I can do this "inserting contents of a file" with `gulp-inject` or if there's something else I should use. Note in the past I tried using `gulp-mustache` but I had problems where it seemed to insert the character (65279). I assume this was something related to the following question, but I was never able to get mustache to work for me:

[How to avoid echoing character 65279 in php? (This question also relates to Javascript xmlhttp.responseText (ajax))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538203/how-to-avoid-echoing-character-65279-in-php-this-question-also-relates-to-java)

I hope someone can give me some advice either with `gulp-inject` or with `gulp-mustache` or any other way to insert the contents of a file in another file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [custom transform function](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject#optionstransform) to inject the contents of the file:

```
gulp.task('watch-index-html', function () {
  gulp.watch(files, function (file) {
    return gulp.src('index/index.html')
      .pipe(inject(gulp.src(['index/base3.html']), {
         starttag: '<!-- inject:base3:html -->',
         transform: function(filepath, file) {
           return file.contents.toString();
         }
      }))
      .pipe(print(function (file) {
        return "Processing " + file;
      }))
     .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
  });
});
```