# line appearing in inspect element but not in HTML code :/

Tags: html, web-inspector

[image report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBqjh.jpg)

So as the title says there are some lines in html i don't get where there are coming from in my local files, i seriously have no idea, any help would be awesome, the line i dont get where it's comming from is the one selected on code inspector.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please paste some code?

Comment: Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538203/how-to-avoid-echoing-character-65279-in-php-this-question-also-relates-to-java).

Comment: @jamaral666 Do you have any javascript for the element `<div class="fh5co-loader"></div>`. I guess thats the one injecting the extra html.

Comment: @Aruna not at all :/

Comment: @anied looking into it, thx =)

Comment: @atefth which part?

Comment: What text editor are you using?

Comment: @atefth dreamweaver

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Macromedia Dreamweaver, follow [this](http://techwelkin.com/how-to-remove-byte-order-mark-bom-characters) guide to disable the BOM.

> Go to *preferences* and find the **New Document** category and uncheck the *Include Unicode Signature (**BOM**)*.

**Note**: *You might have to copy the code to a new file after updating your preference*.