# How to identify FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE characters

Tags: php, character-encoding

I am importing CSV file data,
The first Line is columns name for me, What i found in first column name is,

```
<font color='#cc0000'>'﻿LEG_NO'</font> <i>(length=9)</i>
 0 => string '﻿LEG_NO' (length=9)
```

The LEG_NO Column contains only 6 characters but when I dump in PHP it shows 9 characters, So I searched for this string online [here](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%EF%BB%BFLEG_NO#title), i got FEFF  ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE

Can anybody help me to remove this special character from variable? Which will help me to compare the fields

Comment: No, trim is not removing this special character

Comment: This is almost certainly the result of reading in a file with a Unicode [byte-ordering mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). In your example this is the three byte BOM that specifies the file is encoded as [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (0xEF 0xBB 0xBF).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with a sql file generated by [mssql-scripter](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-xplat-cli) and which I was trying to import with [doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/) using `vendor/bin/doctrine dbal:import file.sql`.

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32321309/4126114)

```
$sql = preg_replace("/\xEF\xBB\xBF/", "", $sql);
```

or use sed on the csv file in your case

```
sed -i "s/\xEF\xBB\xBF//g" file.csv
```