# Smarty assign in prestashop not assign array

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, smarty

guys i want to get from database prestashop category info with module and i use sql query but if i try to assign foreach array prestashop retun me a error code : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)`

This is my code

```
    public function hookDisplayHome()
    {
    $getcategory = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT * FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang`');
    $cattegoryinfo=array();
    foreach($getcategory as $getcategoryinfo){
        $cattegoryinfo[] = array(
         "name" => $getcategoryinfo['name']
         );
    }
         $this->context->smarty->assign('categories', $cattegoryinfo);﻿
         return $this->display(__FILE__,'views/showcategory.tpl');
}
```

Comment: If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

I test your codes and I find a special character after ";" on this line:

```
$this->context->smarty->assign('categories', $cattegoryinfo);
```

Remove it and try again

Answer (score 0):

There is an `&#65279;` character after the semicolon.

maybe this can help you:
[How to avoid echoing character 65279 in php? (This question also relates to Javascript xmlhttp.responseText (ajax))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538203/how-to-avoid-echoing-character-65279-in-php-this-question-also-relates-to-java)