# XML generation using DOMDocument issue

Tags: php, ajax, xml, domdocument, php-5.6

I'm currently trying to generate XML using PHP and DOMDocument class.

```php
// creating xml 'ServiceProfile'
           $xmlServiceProfile = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
           $xmlServiceProfile->formatOutput = true;
           $root = $xmlServiceProfile->createElement('*******');
               $serveur = $xmlServiceProfile->createElement('******', creeServeurLong(*****));
               $archive = $xmlServiceProfile->createElement('******', "******");

           $taskList = $xmlServiceProfile->createElement('******');

               foreach($array as $key => $value) {                   
                   $task = $xmlServiceProfile->createElement($key, $value);                   
                   $taskList->appendChild($task);
               }

           //adding nodes           
           $root->appendChild($******);
           $root->appendChild($******);
           $root->appendChild($******);
           $xmlServiceProfile->appendChild($root);            
           echo $xmlServiceProfile->saveXML();
```

I've got error that mean XML generation failed, but I have a good XML in my http response.

I checked the XML on a website and got

```xml
#65279;<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

I already tryed to :

change document to UTF-8 without BOM, not working

Add `trim()` function on `DOMDocument::saveXML()`

Add `htmlspecialchar()` function on `DOMDocument::saveXML()`

Someone help please?

Comment: Why not use [XMLWriter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php) or [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)? Both are robust XML parsing tools built into PHP and enabled by default.

Comment: Acutally, I never did it before and after google research, this way is most documented in my own language ^^

Comment: Maybe this question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html. That BOM is sneaking in there somehow. It could be related to your text editor somehow. Since it's a zero width space it can be tricky to spot.

Comment: Thanks, I already looked this, but it's not working on my case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid echoing character 65279 in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538203/how-to-avoid-echoing-character-65279-in-php-this-question-also-relates-to-java)